# Dotnetnuke upgrade issue: Name 'Framework' is not declared

Tags: dotnetnuke

I installed Dotnetnuke 4.8 on my site. Then I downloaded upgrade package of 5.1 and upload all file as given http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Wiki/tabid/1409/page/Upgrading-DotNetNuke/Default.aspx

But after upgrading I am getting following error:

```
**Server Error in '/dotnetnuke' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: BC30451: Name 'Framework' is not declared.

Source Error:



Line 49:         ' dynamically create provider
Line 50:         Private Shared Sub CreateProvider()
Line 51:             objProvider = CType(Framework.Reflection.CreateObject("data", "DotNetNuke.Modules.Html", ""), DataProvider)
Line 52:         End Sub
Line 53: 


Source File: C:\inetpub\vhosts\IRFANHYDER.COM\httpdocs\dotnetnuke\App_Code\HTML\DataProvider.vb    Line: 51 
**
```

Any Idea? What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading DNN from that point to 5.1 is a big task and should be done is smaller steps

Try going from 4.8 to 04.09.05
Then to 5.1.1 (link below recommends going to 5.4.4)

See link below for a fuller guide:

REF: http://www.willstrohl.com/Blog/EntryId/102/Suggested-DotNetNuke-Site-Upgrade-Path-s